# System startup and extra logged users

Tags: linux, slackware

I'm running Slackware Linux on  Win7 Virtualbox. When i type a command:

> ps axu | grep bash

i get two instances of bash like so:

> root 1052 ... -bash
>   root 1053 ... -bash

Moreover when i issue `users` command i also get two users logged in (`root root`)

- why is there two root users logged in while i didn't (explicitly) log any extra users except standard login after system startup
- how to diagnose from where that extra logged root user came from and how to log him off?

Comment: Show ouput of `w`.

Answer (score 0):

Systems processes (started as cron jobs, for instance) can appear as bash processes run by root. That doesn't mean a user is logged in.
Use `ps -eaf | grep bash` to have the full command line that started them. That will give you clues about their origin.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to determine where those bashes came from is to do

```
pstree 1
```

and examine who are the parents. For the terminal I did that in, the relevant part of the output is

```
 ├─xfce4-terminal─┬─3*[bash]
 │                ├─bash───tail
 │                ├─bash───pstree
 │                ├─gnome-pty-helpe
 │                ├─{gdbus}
 │                └─{gmain}
```